# What statement should I be using to pull in new data for a subscriber versus repeating data I already have in columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, exclusion-script

I have a large data extension that I am attempting to join multiple types of data that is associated to a single subscriber. So for instance subscriber 123 could have multiple rows of data that I want to assign to that one subscriber in the new target data extension so it's all located in one place. I am able to pull in the first two columns of unique data associated with that subscriber, but then in the 3rd row, I am pulling in and repeating the data from the first field/column again.

Below is the query I am currently using to pull in the 3rd field/column of data, which is supposed to pull in any new data that is not already in fields/columns 1 or 2 before it.

**Original Query that is pulling in repeat data that has already been placed in target data extension.**

```sql
select 
subid
, petID as 'petid3'
, birthday as 'birthday3'
, petbr as 'petbr3'
, petnm as 'petnm3'
, petsp as 'petsp3' 
from XYZde with(nolock) 
where petid in (
   select 
   max(petid) 
   from XYZde with(nolock) 
   where petid not in (
     select 
     petid2 
     from [Master DE] 
     where petid2 is not null   
   ) 
group by subID
)
```

**Since it is repeating the first row of data, I have tried adding in an OR statement to now exclude the first column of data such as this:** (but this isn't working either)

```
select petid2 OR petid1 
from [Master DE] 
where petid2 OR petid1 is not null) group by subID)
```

**To summarize:** Trying to identify how to adjust my query to pull in any new data that is associated with subscriber 123 that is not already in the target data extension, however the OR statement I tried using above isn't working either. Is it possible I need an OR statement and an IF statement?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask what the use case is? If you want to put any of this data into an email, you'd be better off using AMPscript to pull from your 1:many data extension. If this is for segmentation, you could use SQL to get your target DE or create a data relationship to use drag and drop filtering.

Comment: Sure! The use case is to join data from multiple data extensions into one master data extension using a SQL query activity. Does that answer your question? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I understand this but I'm not clear on why it's necessary? Is it to help non-technical users with segmentation for example?

Comment: The end goal will be to have all data for a customer in one data extension. It's difficult to explain, but basically as it's set up now, a customers data could be on different rows, limiting us when it comes to segmenting via email. But yes ultimately it will help when creating email send lists because all data would be in one data extension (allowing the ability to then create filtered data extensions).

Comment: Please update your question to include a data sample from `XYZde` and `[Master DE]` and the desired output of the query.